Search and Replace in a string with multiple phrases at once
I would like to replace this code with a more efficient one:
String s = "The brown fox is jumping over a fence";
s = s.replace(s, "brown", "black");
s = s.replace(s, "fox", "dog");
s = s.replace(s, "fence", "pond");
System.out.println(s);

The above code is running though the long text 3 times and creating new strings every time. Is there some library that can do the same job with only one iteration through the long text.
I would use StringBuilder, go through the text char by char and try to find one of the search phrases and then try to efficiently create a new text.
But I don't want to implement myself, I'm looking for a already existing library method for this. (Apache, Google, ....)
Thank you.

Map<String, String> m = Map.of("brown", "black", "fox", "dog", "fence", "pond");String s2 = new Scanner(s).tokens().map(t ->m.getOrDefault(t, t)).collect(Collectors.joining(" ")); would be pretty efficient

@g00se Your solution also might have issues if any token happened to occur as a substring of a larger word, e.g. fenced would be replaced by your one-liner.

@TimBiegeleisen No, because the token would be fenced, which is not a key in the Map, the keys of which don't operate via substringing

If you really wanted to make only one pass through the string, you could do a regex search on an alternation, then selectively do replacements based on each particular match.  For example:
String s = "The brown fox is jumping over a fence";
String pattern = "\\b(?:brown|fox|fence)\\b";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(s);
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

while (m.find()) {
    switch (m.group()) {
        case "brown":
            m.appendReplacement(buffer, "black");
            break;
        case "fox":
            m.appendReplacement(buffer, "dog");
            break;
        case "fence":
            m.appendReplacement(buffer, "pond");
            break;
    }
}

m.appendTail(buffer);

System.out.println(buffer.toString());    // The black dog is jumping over a pond

The above code is very verbose, but if you were doing this replacement on on a very large text (think 100+MB to GB size), then there could be a performance boost by simply making one pass over the text, rather than separate passes for each search term.

You can try apach's StringUtils
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
</dependency>

StringUtils.replaceEachRepeatedly();
StringUtils.replaceEach()

/**
 * <p>
 * Replaces all occurrences of Strings within another String.
 * </p>
 *
 * <p>
 * A {@code null} reference passed to this method is a no-op, or if
 * any "search string" or "string to replace" is null, that replace will be
 * ignored.
 * </p>
 *
 * <pre>
 *  StringUtils.replaceEachRepeatedly(null, *, *) = null
 *  StringUtils.replaceEachRepeatedly("", *, *) = ""
 *  StringUtils.replaceEachRepeatedly("aba", null, null) = "aba"
 *  StringUtils.replaceEachRepeatedly("aba", new String[0], null) = "aba"
 *  StringUtils.replaceEachRepeatedly("aba", null, new String[0]) = "aba"
 *  StringUtils.replaceEachRepeatedly("aba", new String[]{"a"}, null) = "aba"
 *  StringUtils.replaceEachRepeatedly("aba", new String[]{"a"}, new String[]{""}) = "b"
 *  StringUtils.replaceEachRepeatedly("aba", new String[]{null}, new String[]{"a"}) = "aba"
 *  StringUtils.replaceEachRepeatedly("abcde", new String[]{"ab", "d"}, new String[]{"w", "t"}) = "wcte"
 *  (example of how it repeats)
 *  StringUtils.replaceEachRepeatedly("abcde", new String[]{"ab", "d"}, new String[]{"d", "t"}) = "tcte"
 *  StringUtils.replaceEachRepeatedly("abcde", new String[]{"ab", "d"}, new String[]{"d", "ab"}) = IllegalStateException
 * </pre>
 *
 * @param text
 *            text to search and replace in, no-op if null
 * @param searchList
 *            the Strings to search for, no-op if null
 * @param replacementList
 *            the Strings to replace them with, no-op if null
 * @return the text with any replacements processed, {@code null} if
 *         null String input
 * @throws IllegalStateException
 *             if the search is repeating and there is an endless loop due
 *             to outputs of one being inputs to another
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException
 *             if the lengths of the arrays are not the same (null is ok,
 *             and/or size 0)
 * @since 2.4
 */
public static String replaceEachRepeatedly(final String text, final String[] searchList, final String[] replacementList) {
    // timeToLive should be 0 if not used or nothing to replace, else it's
    // the length of the replace array
    final int timeToLive = searchList == null ? 0 : searchList.length;
    return replaceEach(text, searchList, replacementList, true, timeToLive);
}

/**
 * <p>
 * Replaces all occurrences of Strings within another String.
 * </p>
 *
 * <p>
 * A {@code null} reference passed to this method is a no-op, or if
 * any "search string" or "string to replace" is null, that replace will be
 * ignored. This will not repeat. For repeating replaces, call the
 * overloaded method.
 * </p>
 *
 * <pre>
 *  StringUtils.replaceEach(null, *, *)        = null
 *  StringUtils.replaceEach("", *, *)          = ""
 *  StringUtils.replaceEach("aba", null, null) = "aba"
 *  StringUtils.replaceEach("aba", new String[0], null) = "aba"
 *  StringUtils.replaceEach("aba", null, new String[0]) = "aba"
 *  StringUtils.replaceEach("aba", new String[]{"a"}, null)  = "aba"
 *  StringUtils.replaceEach("aba", new String[]{"a"}, new String[]{""})  = "b"
 *  StringUtils.replaceEach("aba", new String[]{null}, new String[]{"a"})  = "aba"
 *  StringUtils.replaceEach("abcde", new String[]{"ab", "d"}, new String[]{"w", "t"})  = "wcte"
 *  (example of how it does not repeat)
 *  StringUtils.replaceEach("abcde", new String[]{"ab", "d"}, new String[]{"d", "t"})  = "dcte"
 * </pre>
 *
 * @param text
 *            text to search and replace in, no-op if null
 * @param searchList
 *            the Strings to search for, no-op if null
 * @param replacementList
 *            the Strings to replace them with, no-op if null
 * @return the text with any replacements processed, {@code null} if
 *         null String input
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException
 *             if the lengths of the arrays are not the same (null is ok,
 *             and/or size 0)
 * @since 2.4
 */
public static String replaceEach(final String text, final String[] searchList, final String[] replacementList) {
    return replaceEach(text, searchList, replacementList, false, 0);
}

